# warning in ./resources/js/plugins/i18n.js "export 'default' (imported as 'VueI18n') was not found in 'vue-i18n' : Vue I18n VueJS Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-i18n

I'm tri to use vue i18n in my project Laravel / Vue but I have this error message

> warning  in ./resources/js/plugins/i18n.js
>
> "export 'default' (imported as 'VueI18n') was not found in 'vue-i18n'

This is my app.js :

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';
import {i18n} from './plugins/i18n'

document.body.setAttribute('data-app', true)
Vue.component('equipe-component', require('./components/Researchteam.vue').default);
Vue.component('atlas-component', require('./components/Atlas.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
   
  el: '#app',
    vuetify,
    i18n, 
    
  });
```

This is my plugins/i18n.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
Vue.use(VueI18n)

export const i18n = new VueI18n({
    fallbackLocale: 'en',
    locale: 'fr',
    messages: {
        fr: {
            messages: "Hello"
        },
        en: {
            messages: "bonjour"
        }
    }
    
})
```